# how to SELECT rows BETWEEN a list of ranges

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, between

I am using the JPA with JPQL queries to retrieve data from a MySQL DB. But my problem is rather logical than language specific (I think)...

**I would like to `SELECT` all entries of a table `WHERE` one column is in `BETWEEN` a list of ranges.**

For example:

```
SELECT x FROM myTable 
WHERE x BETWEEN 2 AND 5 
   OR x BETWEEN 7 AND 9
```

While the ranges (2-5, 7-9) come from another table:

```
 RANGES         ex:   id | from | to
––––––––––            –––––––––––––––
 id:   INT              1|     2|   5
 from: INT              2|     7|   9
 to:   INT              3|     9|  15
                        4|    17| null
```

**My problem a)**
is, that the `Ranges` list is dynamic and could be either only one range, like 
  `x BETWEEN 2 AND 5` 
or multiple ranges like
  `x BETWEEN 2 AND 5 OR x BETWEEN 7 AND 9 OR x BETWEEN ....`

**My problem b)**
is, that the `Ranges` could also be open like
  `x >= 17`

**My problem c)**
is, that there are other `WHERE` conditions, limiting the results. Some of those `WHERE` conditions are more "limiting" than the `BETWEEN` conditions. So they come first, to make the whole query faster. Let's say for example
  `... WHERE x%2=0 AND x BETWEEN 2 AND 5`

For **c)** I thought about sub-queries, for example:

```
SELECT x FROM myTable 
WHERE x IN (
        SELECT x FROM myTable 
        WHERE x BETWEEN 2 AND 5 
          OR  x BETWEEN 7 AND 9
     )
 AND y .. something something
```

The "good" thing is, I use Java and the JPA to create my queries, so I could create the queries *dynamically*. But before abusing String concatenation to dynamically create SQL queries, I was hoping to find a cleaner solution in pure SQL (or even better in JPQL)

Comment: How could x be between both (2 and 5) AND (7 and 9) ? Try with an OR

Comment: Sorry for that. Yes of course I meant OR :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First `and` is the wrong logic.  "x" cannot be both between 2 and 5 and 7 and 9.  It is a mathematical impossibility.  So, I assume you intend `or`.

Then, you can do this with `exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where t1.x between t2.fromval and t2.toval
             );
```

Comment: I can't believe it so "simple" :) Thank you so much!! Out of curiosity: what does the `1` in `select 1 from..` do exactly?

Comment: @GameDroids you have to select one column when using exists.  Selecting 1 is the easiest/fastest way of doing it.  But you could select "Hey I am really hungry" and it would still work.

Comment: @StanShaw Interesting! Thanks for explaining. I guess I'll stick to `1` then :)

Answer (score 2):

Answering the problem (b):

You should change WHERE condition in @Gordon-Linoff answer if you have conditions with open bounds:

```
 where (t1.x between t2.fromval and t2.toval)
       OR ((t1.x >= t2.fromval)  AND (t2.toval IS NULL))
       OR ((t1.x <= t2.toval)  AND (t2.fromval IS NULL))
       OR ((t2.toval IS NULL) AND (t2.fromval IS NULL)) --super conditions always TRUE :)
```

Also you can use this condition:

```
where t1.x between COALESCE(t2.fromval,t1.x) and COALESCE(t2.toval,t1.x)
```

Comment: thanks ! I just started to work on problem b :) For now I think I'll go with `where t1.x between t2.fromval and COALESCE(t2.toval,t1.x)` . Didn't know  `COALESCE` before - such a nice command

Comment: Upvoting for Coalesce